# Translating "kind words" (as in "Thank you for your kind words.")

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

In English if someone complements you or expresses their gratitude for something you've done, you can respond with something like, "Thank you for your kind words."

What Spanish phrase would best translate that sense of "kind words"?

Comment: This translation is easily found in a dictionary that provides phrases. Check [this page](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=kind) from the site Wordreference.com... Sorry, I'm voting to close (no hard feelings... :) eheh).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would transate it to *amables palabras*:

> Gracias por tus amables palabras.

Comment: Is it normally *amables palabras* or *palabras amables* (as Alenanno's link above says)?

Comment: Both of them are used: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=amables+palabras%2C+palabras+amables&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=10&smoothing=3 , but *amables palabras* emphasizes more the word *amable*.